# On the localized screening of cerium (when compared to iron)

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory

I was reading the paper 'A linear response approach to the calculation of the effective interaction parameters in the LDA+U method' by Cococcioni - ([Paper here)](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0405160) .

Quoting from the first paragraph on page 9, 'The screening in metallic cerium is extremely localized..'. Even though this section deals with the calculation of the Hubbard 'U', I suspect that the reasoning for this isn't complicated. To furnish more context, the authors compare the results of metallic cerium with metallic ion (from the previous section in the paper).

To recapitulate, the assertion here is that the screening in metallic cerium is extremely localized when compared to metallic iron. I know this is directly related to the electronic configuration, but I would be happy if someone would be able to provide an explanation for this.

PS: I cross-posted this on Chemistry Stack Exchange because I deemed that forum to be  equally appropriate to approach the problem at hand. (But couldn't get an answer there)

Comment: Those f-electron wave functions are much more directional than s, p, or d electrons.

Comment: Could you elaborate @JonCuster. I still don't get what the authors mean by 'screening is localized (for the 4f states) in Cerium compared to Iron'..